# dynamic rows and columns in VBA Chart

Tags: vba, dynamic, charts

so i am trying to write some VBA that can look at "sheet2" and determine how many rows and columns it needs to make in its line chart

i'm having difficulty in declaring range of .SetSourceData in terms of variable i need it to start at cell(1,4) and go to Cell(LastRow, LastColumn). when i try i get a error

'method 2
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim ShName As String
With ActiveSheet

```
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 4), .Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

' ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("R2").Value = rng2

```
ShName = .Name
End With

Charts.Add

With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData Source:=rng2
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I try use you code and get error in line:

```
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 4), .Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

try add `ThisWorkbook` before `.Sheets`:

```
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 4), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

or remove dot before `Sheets`:

```
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 4), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```